# Adding a wall in the garage. Did I mess up by not getting a permit?

Tags: walls, garage, permitting

I am adding a wall in my garage. I want to eventually put a door from that portion of the garage into the house and air condition it. For now, I started putting up a wall with one outlet and a door into the unfinished portion of the garage. I have a lot of electrical and construction experience so this was not hard. However, I want to add this 200 square feet as living space eventually when I sell or rent. Can I get a permit later for the door and air conditioning and be okay? Or did I need a permit for the wall? I live in Pinellas Fl.

Comment: The walls between a garage and a living space typically need to be fire rated. Did you take that into account?

Comment: Make sure you reread the rules.  Where it says "over 500$ and needs an inspection", make sure that 'and' is not an 'or'.  A plain wall is probably okay, a wall with electrical/plumbing usually needs an inspection.

Comment: Not all places require inspections (at all), but those who do typically require inspections when building habitable space (which you're doing).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [register](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting responses as answers can result in an automated lock that would prevent others from assisting you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to ask your Local Authority Having Jurisdiction, which might be your town or city, county, or (rarely) state.

Unpermitted work can be very expensive. They may choose to fine you from whenever you finally get a permit all the way back to when you first built it (often don't but it's one of the big threats they have and *can* choose to use.) They may make you rip it all out, get permits, do it over. (That one's fairly common - They can't see if the framings wrong, or the electrical or plumbing with drywall over it.) They may come inspect it, slap a huge or not so huge fine on you for not permitting it, and go on with their day. Depends on the LAHJ.

If you build it complete (past the point where it can be inspected) without getting it permitted and inspected, the above options get more expensive and are less likely not to involve ripping it down again.

I think my town (which is my LAHJ) the first option was $50 per day from the day you started it until the day you got a permit for it some years ago. It may be even more now. Let that stew a couple of years and you're into serious money.

You might want to look into what your local rules say and consider quietly taking the wall down again; then getting a permit before putting it up again, which will likely cost considerably less than potential fines.